# Query teradata to hive

Tags: sql, date, hive, casting, teradata

I have this teradata query, but when I run it on hive it doesn't support it

```
CAST(DATE '1900-01-01'+CAST( 999999999 - TRIM(BASM_DATE) AS INTEGER)  
AS DATE) AS BASM_DATE
```

Error

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 
0:undefined:-1 Wrong arguments 'BASM_DATE': No matching method for class 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPDTIPlus with (date, 
int)
```

can you guys tell me which part to fix and what the query will be?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `date_add(dt,num)`.

Pls use below SQL -

```
date_add( '1900-01-01',  999999999 - cast( TRIM(BASM_DATE) as INT) ) AS BASM_DATE
```

I assumed BASM_DATE is a string column and using `TRIM` you are trying to remove trailing or leading spaces.

Comment: the basm_date column is of date data type

Comment: ok then you need to use date_sub as well

Comment: replace date_add with date_sub? what is the difference between date_add and date_sub?

Comment: They are complimentary. add some number to date using date_add, and subtract some number from date use date_sub. also i mentioned using date_sub to calculate 9999- trim(basm_date) part. everything else will remain as is

Comment: can you show me what the query would look like if adding date_sub or combining date_add with date_sub

Answer (score 0):

The Teradata SQL is relying on two implicit conversions that happen around the TRIM.

First the BASM_DATE is implicitly cast to VARCHAR using the default format, then TRIM is applied, then that string is implicitly cast to FLOAT followed by a floating-point subtraction, with that result explicitly cast to INTEGER. Then that number of days is added to the 1900-01-01 date, followed by a redundant CAST from DATE to DATE. (There's really no reason to use FLOAT here, that's just the type Teradata uses for implicit numeric conversions.) A better, clearer choice in Teradata that gives the same result would have been:

```
DATE'1900-01-01'+(999999999 - CAST(TO_CHAR(BASM_DATE,'YYYYMMDD') AS INTEGER) AS BASM_DATE
```

So the Hive equivalent would be:

```
date_add('1900-01-01',999999999 - cast(date_format(BASM_DATE,'yyyyMMdd') AS INT)) AS BASM_DATE
```

or it may be more efficient to use

```
date_add('1900-01-01',999999999 - year(BASM_DATE)*10000 - month(BASM_DATE)*100 - day(BASM_DATE)) AS BASM_DATE
```